# MySQL: Importing CSV file from script

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have script to parse some data and save the data into Output.csv (Output.csv is located on server (/tmp) ) Then I want to import this Output.csv in to a MySQL existing table.

```
        with open("/tmp/Output.csv", "w",0600) as text_file:
          text_file.write(csv)
          mydbs.connect()     
          mydbs.sqlcmd("""LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/Output.csv' INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ;""")
          text_file.close()
          os.remove("/tmp/Output.csv")
```

SQL query works in some way, for example if I change "my_table" to "my_tableasd" I get an error:

> ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'dbs.my_tableasd' doesn't exist").

Also I can do any kind of Selects but this import simply does not work. I don't get any errors or warnings..nothing, but when I have a look into PHPmyAdmin there is no data imported.

I tried to import Output.csv through PhpMyAdmin and it works..

I also tried to set local-infile=1 to my.cnf ([mysql], [mysqld]) but nothing happened

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I tried to close database and it works. It's interesting because I never do that in whole project and I'm working with dbs all the time, but maybe this import needs to be submitted or smth like that

```
mydbs.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Close the file before you try to import it.

Answer (score 0):

Separate writting and processing:

```
with open("/tmp/Output.csv", "w",0600) as text_file:
    text_file.write(csv)

mydbs.connect()     
mydbs.sqlcmd("""
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/Output.csv'
    INTO TABLE my_table
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ;
""")

os.remove("/tmp/Output.csv")
```